# Trouble tracing through pass-by-reference and pass-by-value-result

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following program:

```
begin
    integer i;

    procedure pass(x, y);
        integer x, y;
        begin
            x := x+1;
            y := x+1;
            x := y;
            i := i+ 1
        end

    i := 1;
    pass(i,i);
    print i
end
```

I can work through the pass-by-value answer, but what would the pass-by-reference and pass-by-value-result traces look like?

Comment: ML? Really? This is ML?

Comment: Ugh, got my languages mixed up. It's Algol-like pseudocode, but the parameter passing should be language agnostic.

Comment: So what's the problem with it? Pass by reference: replace all occurrences of `x` and `y` with `i` in the procedure body. Is it hard to trace?

Comment: Pass by value-result is ill-defined if you pass the same variable twice, so if you want it to be well-defined you need to define some order of result passing.